# Find best longitude/latitude match from an array of possible locations

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a plist with 12 objects with unique keys (let's say 1, 2, 3, etc). Each object contains an array (key: `clubLocations`) with 100 - 200 objects.

Each object in the `clubLocations` array contains a `longitude` and `latitude` key with a club's location.

I would like some assistance in creating a method which loops through **each** object **for every** clubLocations **in every** 12 objects and finds out which clubLocation is the closest match to the users coordinates.

So basically object 1/2/3/etc -> clubLocations objectAtIndex:0/1/2/3/etc -> best match?

I have the user's coordinates, so "just" need assistance to find the closest locations from my plist. Thank you in advance and please do not hesitate to ask in a comment if I am not making myself clear enough.

Comment: Do you need assistance for calculating the distance, or you want to know how to program a loop?

Comment: Assistance to figure out which location is the closest based on its long/lat and the user's long/lat, whether that be available frameworks or through loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
min_distance = MAXINT
closest = None
for obj in objects:
  for club in obj.clubLocations:
    d = distance(club.longitude, club.latitude, user.longitude, user.latitude)
    if d < min_distance:
      min_distance = d
      closest = club
```

Comment: Thanks. While this wouldn't count as a complete answer, I did select it. It lead me to `CLLocationDistance` which is built in and quickly calculates the distance from two `CLLocations`, in case anyone else was looking for this solution :)